# Time Difference between Two rows excluding weekend and Time stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

| Date | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-07 17:30:00.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-10-10 10:00:00.000 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-10-12 08:31:42.000 | 3 | 1 |

I want to find date difference from two rows with few conditions in MS SQL

1. Difference should be from 9am - 6pm (exclude rest of the time)
2. Also Exclude weekends.

For example, Date Diff from first row will be 1 hr 30 mins.

I am using this query:

```
 DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(date) OVER (ORDER BY date), date)
```

How can I add more conditions to this?

Comment: "*Date Diff from first row will be 1 hr 30 mins.*" - Can you explain the math behind this output, given your input data?

Comment: Row 1 Date  = 2022-10-07 17:30:00.000  means Friday 5.30 PM
Row 2 Date  = 2022-10-10 10:00:00.000  means Monday  10.00 AM

Comment: `LAG(Row 1 Date)` is NULL. Also difference between Row 2 Date and Row 1 Date is ~3+ days. How do you compute "*1 hr 30 mins*" from Row 1 Date?

Comment: Sorry Their is one row above also forgot to add here and that row diff is null but if you understand my query, I want date diff from two dates with some conditions which I have mentioned above

Comment: No problem, Stack Overflow allows you to update your post. Also consider adding a full expected output table along with your updated input table.

Comment: Did you find any solution on this ?

Comment: Please update your question with the expected result for the rest of the rows also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, let's compute the values we need to handle, namely the current date (that we already have as a field) and the previous date (using the `LAG` window function, as you did in your attempt).

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [date] AS curDate, 
           LAG([date]) OVER(ORDER BY date) AS prevDate
    FROM tab
)
```

---

**CASE 1**: prevDate's day is equal to curDate's day

In this case we just need to apply the difference in minutes between the two dates as follows:

```
CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, curDate) = CONVERT(DATE, prevDate)
     THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, prevDate, curDate)
```

---

**CASE 2**: prevDate's day is not equal to curDate's day

Here we need to compute three things:

- the difference in time between endtime (18:00:00) and prevDate's time

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(prevDate AS TIME), '18:00:00')
```

- the difference in time between starttime (9:00:00) and curDate's time

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '9:00:00', CAST(curDate AS TIME))
```

- the difference in days between curDate and prevDate. For this last one there's the caveat regarding the weekend days though. We can solve this problem by checking if the day of week of curDate is smaller than the day of week of prevDate (if prevDate's working date is Friday and curDate's working date is Monday, we will have dayofweek = 2 for Monday and dayofweek = 6 for Friday, whereas 2-6<0). If the result is smaller than 0, then we need to subtract 3 days of work (multiplied by 9 days of working activity for each day - 18:00:00-9:00:00).

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '9:00:00', CAST(curDate AS TIME))   +
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(prevDate AS TIME), '18:00:00') +
9*(DATEDIFF(DAY, prevDate, curDate) -
   CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, curDate) - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, prevDate) > 1  
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 3 END
  )
```

---

Hence the **Final Query** would be the following one:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [date] AS curDate, 
           LAG([date]) OVER(ORDER BY date) AS prevDate
    FROM tab
)
SELECT curDate,
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, curDate) = CONVERT(DATE, prevDate)
            THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, prevDate, curDate)
            ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '9:00:00', CAST(curDate AS TIME))   +
                 DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(prevDate AS TIME), '18:00:00') +
                 9*(DATEDIFF(DAY, prevDate, curDate) -
                    CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, curDate) - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, prevDate) > 1
                         THEN 0 
                         ELSE 3 END)
       END
FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/D4byz7_B).